# How to transfer file to SFTP path using SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sftp, winscp

How to transfer files to the provided SFTP paths using SSIS package.

Thanks in advance for your valuable replies.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool, software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_ - Saying you NEED something without demonstrating any thought input other than spouting requirements isn't enough. SO won't write the code for you, or do your work for you. Show what you have attempted to do to solve your dilema, and people can comment on how to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this link..
This works perfectly ,i recently implemented same.
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis#example

Thanks